# Rails form_tag only returns last input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm creating a specific helper for my page using the rails `form_tag` helper. Here is my code:

```
  def horta_form(form, args = {})
    set_editable(form) unless args[:editable] == false
    identifier, send_to, classes, style = form.identifier, form.send_to, form.classes, form.style
    form_tag("/contact", method: "post") do
      text_field_tag('name')
      text_field_tag('email')
      text_area_tag('message')
      submit_tag('Send')
    end
  end
```

But in my view, it only renders the last tag, the `submit_tag`.

```
<%= horta_form(@form) %>
```

returns

```
<form action="/contact" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="/WLo9GzhGdD7dBk3Eh8k4Q/+jQ0r+EGqgoOXBedyl/NW6g5gBQ/R4U4gFEtXmz1xJlISHAYykZRkmDHhQJm8uQ==">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send" data-disable-with="Send">
</form>
```

What should I do to make the `horta_form` return the form with all inputs, not just the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat` when you need nested structure in your helpers:

```
def horta_form(form, args = {})
  #...
  form_tag("/contact", method: "post") do
    concat text_field_tag('name')
    concat text_field_tag('email')
    concat text_area_tag('message')
    concat submit_tag('Send')
  end
end
```